# A weird uninterpreted HTML tag on Stack Overflow when JavaScript was disabled

Tags: support, javascript

I was looking for the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object in a source page of Stack Overflow and couldn't find one. So, I tried switching off JavaScript in my browser ([Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome)) to confirm whether Stack Overflow uses [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and found this weird HTML tag, `<div id="noscript-padding"></div>`, rendered uninterpreted at the top of the page.

[image]

Is that a bug?

Comment: SO isn't meant to be viewed without JS, so the fact that you saw odd things can't be helped.

Comment: @Asad: but then again the `noscript` id suggests that this was added *specifically* for JavaScript-less clients in mind, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: That is a webkit bug. Anything inside the `<noscript>` tag is treated as a text node when the page is loaded with JavaScript enabled. If you turn off JavaScript after the page is loaded, the `<noscript>` content may be shown as plain text. It is rendered correctly only when you load the page with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: I normally see a red bar on the top saying that I have scripts disabled in browser.

Comment: ...... _element_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232410), where the content of the `<noscript>` tag is incorrectly interpreted as text the first time. It should be fine on subsequent refreshes, and there's not much that can be done about it on the Stack Exchange's end.